# I can't able to return HTML file in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-thymeleaf

This is my controller class

In this controller add get values in mypage html and store in the db that I host everything work perfectly but in `processAdduserForm` class was return that exact string in webpage not the html file
I am encountering an issue with my Spring Boot application where my controller class is returning the exact string instead of rendering the corresponding HTML file in the web page. Below, I'll provide details of my setup and the steps I've taken so far:

```java
@PostMapping("/add")
public String processAddUserForm(
        @RequestParam String name,
        @RequestParam String email,
        @RequestParam Integer age,
        @RequestParam String dept,
        @RequestParam Integer salarey,
        @RequestParam String password,
        Model model) {
    // Create a new user and save it to the database
    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.setName(name);
    newUser.setEmail(email);
    newUser.setAge(age);
    newUser.setDept(dept);
    newUser.setSalarey(salarey);
    newUser.setPassword(password);

    userRepository.save(newUser);

    // Pass data to the success page
    model.addAttribute("name", name);

    // Redirect to the success page
    return "Success";
}
```

This is my html location:

[image]

Here is success html controller

```java
@GetMapping("/success")
public String showSuccessPage() {
    return "Success";
}
```

These are my application properties I give correct prefix and suffix only but it not call the success html file in the templates folder.

When I give path `http://loaclhost:8080/demo/success` it shows the success html page. When I return my html success page name in string method its not return the html file.

This is my application properties in that I give prefix and suffix also but it not call the html file in webpage:

```bash
# application.properties

spring.mvc.view.prefix=classpath:/templates
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

I except when my controller class return Success string its need to call Success html page in my localhost
help me I am stuck in this step

Comment: Let me guess you have `@RestController` instead of `@Controller` on your controller.

Comment: ^ This. You should post your `WebController` (class names should be PascalCase) as well.

Comment: First, when you ```return "Success"``` you are actually forwarding to a non-existent "Success" view (your view is lower case "success"), not redirecting. You may have also mistakenly annotated your controller as a rest controller. In addition, if you have annotated your controller as a ```@Controller``` you need to return "redirect:/success" to actually perform the redirect and you need to be using ```RedirectAttributes``` and ```addFlashAttribute()``` for your name to survive the redirect. Take a look at [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward) for more info on redirects.

Comment: @LeeGreiner: His template is `Success.html` so that's ok with uppercase. Also I think he is mistakenly redirect for forwarding, so it seems ok this far.

Comment: @Slevin You are correct about the view's case. Typically, you redirect after post and his comment indicated redirect so I added the info about the redirect.